# Storing and retrieving width and height attributes to return price per item

Tags: ms-access, schema, ms-access-2016

I have a client who sells products that have width and height attributes:
1. Measurements are taken from an architectural plan or measured onsite
2. Width and height are rounded to the nearest 100mm
3. Staff member looks up the rounded width across columns in a pdf table (or a spreadsheet) then finds the corresponding height
4. Intersection of the column and row gives the base cost per item

**NOTE:**  These base costs are not linear and cannot be calculated (if only!!); each width/height price must be stored.

There are many products (~20) each of which has a different base cost per unit based on its width and height.  I have created a spreadsheet version which is fairly straightforward, but I am grappling with how to store this in Access...any articles/examples I have found have price as a single column and based on SKU; simple but not how this pricing model works.

Any ideas on how to structure the data?  Huge thanks in advance...

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest schema is a table with three columns: `Width`, `Height`, `Cost`

Define a unique index containing both Width and Height columns.  To find a particular cost, search (filter or join) on the Width and Height columns.

This schema will require that you have duplicate width and height values (although each pair should be unique), but that's the nature of relational table design.  It may not seems as "efficient" as the visual lookup capability of the original table since in that case you only label each Width column and each Height row once, but the index defined on the table provides the necessary, efficient lookup mechanism.

Comment: Thanks so much...that is going to be a little ugly (approx 1700 WxH combinations per product) but I can see that it will work.  Much appreciated!

Comment: To someone unaccustomed to relational tables, this can seem "ugly" and awkward compared to spreadsheets.  But there really _should be no more Access table rows than there are cross-reference cells_. Access can handle millions of records efficiently if they are indexed properly, so the overall size of the access table is a non-issue. If you are worried about presentation, there are betters ways of presenting the data to users other than simply listing the raw table values.  For example, you could re-generate the entire--or just portions--of the cross-reference view similar to Excel.

Comment: Have put together a proof of concept now and it's working quite nicely...not 100% sure how we're going to update pricing in future, but I suspect I'll hustle up some sort of spreadsheet that converts the tables in to a contiguous list with the appropriate indices.  Thanks again for your help, it really is appreciated!